# How do I create a Regex pattern to match an ordered sequence of substrings?

Tags: regex, string, validation

I have a multiline piece of text that I'm trying to validate has a certain set of substrings in an expected order.  For example:

```
orange: VGHM00112900837-00692
   banana: LAPM00112900837-00692_1
      apple: CAPM00112900837-00692
```

I need to validate that the text starts with "orange", then has "banana", then has "apple".  Characters in between these substrings do no matter, but they must be in the sequence orange, banana, apple.  Most importantly, each substring can only occur once in this sequence.

I have been sitting here for several hours tweaking in an online Regex tester and my cro-magnon brain is too dense to figure it out.  The closest I can get is the following...

```
^(?s)orange(.*)banana(.*)apple(.*)$
```

...but that would allow repeats within the string.  I have tried many different suggestions from around stackoverflow and for some reason I just cannot get it right.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\borange\b(?:(?!\b(?:banana|apple|orange)\b)[\s\S])*?\bbanana\b(?:(?!\b(?:orange|apple|banana)\b)[\s\S])*?\bapple\b(?:(?!\b(?:orange|apple|banana)\b)[\s\S])*
```

You can construct your regex using `lookahead` to make sure each string appears only once.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/31

Comment: Yep, I just played with it some and it's solid.  Thanks so much!  I'm going to have to break it down and understand it before I will feel comfortable using it, though (the regex101 site does a good job helping with that).